# Адаптивность и макет

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Появился вопрос по поводу макета. Дело в том, что сайту нужен адаптив, соответственно нужно понимание, как всё будет отображаться на разных экранах. То есть, к примеру, что делать с меню - прятать его под бургер? Что делать с эффектом при ховере(при наведении на другой пункт меню он должен двигаться), сколько блоков должно отображаться в Live-ленте.

Поэтому, нужно знать, как всё будет выглядеть на устройствах с разными разрешениями. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайнер говорит, что он сделал макет и по этому макету должна делаться адаптивность, то есть работа верстальщика придумать, как это будет выглядеть. 
Так, собственно, это работа верстальщика и дизайнера? Скрины макета ниже, макет на 1920px.

Еще одна страница, к сожалению из-за размера не получается загрузить на Stakeoverflow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KLaw.jpg
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если работа почасовая, не вижу проблем и самому заадаптировать, а потом ещё недельку правки повносить .. если плата за проект, то тут уже надо по деньгам опять же ориентироваться, если это не было заложено в изначальную смету, то пускай сами решают пересчитывать тебе или дизайнеру. Короче все упирается в деньги и кому доплачивать. Хотя конечно странный вопрос для этой площадки.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, в данной ситуации денежный вопрос не играет роли. Просто нужно понять: видение, как должен отображаться макет на разных устройствах должен предоставлять дизайнер или верстальщик?

Comment: кто хочет тот и делает. В идеале это задача дизайнера. На практике когда как. Если денежный вопрос тут не решает, то кач-веннее и быстрее было бы заставить дизайнера сделать макеты под разные устройства. А так .. не знаю, в моей практике все упирается в "кому за что заплачено - тот то и делает". Мне сложно оценить данную ситуацию, так как я не понимаю, как это деньги роли не играют и раз не играют, то почему вообще возник такой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

В идеале, дизайнеру нужно делать макет в psd слоями. Так чтоб можно было включить слой "кнопка нажата" и кнопка в макете меняется наложением на неё такого же слоя, но с другим дизайном кнопки. На этапе дизайна можно вообще разрисовать любые действия с элементами, вопрос только в целесообразности. Если при наведении на кнопку будет только добавляться тень - то это уже проще верстальщику сделать, т.к. иначе макет будет избыточным. А вот уже как будет отображаться, например, меню - сендвичем\сверху\снизу\в бок - это уже часть дизайна.